# change state with hooks returns Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some strange reason when trying to change the array using setState (hooks) I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined.

Tried console logging the array `count` and I am getting all the listed items back.

Clicking on the `handleDelete` event gives me that error.

Am I using React Hooks the wrong way?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// Components
import NavBar from './components/navbar';
import Counters from './components/counters';

import './App.css';

const App = () => {
    const [count, setCounters] = useState({
        data: [
            {
                id: 1,
                value: 4,
            },

            {
                id: 2,
                value: 0,
            },

            {
                id: 3,
                value: 0,
            },

            {
                id: 4,
                value: 0,
            },
        ],
    });

    const handleIncrement = counter => {
        const counters = [...count.data];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);

        counters[index] = { ...counter };
        counters[index].value++;

        setCounters(counters);
    };

    const handleDecrement = counter => {
        const counters = [...count.data];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);

        counters[index] = { ...counter };
        counters[index].value--;

        setCounters(counters);
    };

    const handleReset = () => {
        const counters = count.data.map(c => {
            c.value = 0;
            return c;
        });

        setCounters(counters);
    };

    const handleDelete = counterId => {
        const counters = count.data.filter(c => c.id !== counterId);

        setCounters(counters);
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <NavBar
                totalCounters={count.data.filter(c => c.value > 0).length}
            />
            <main className="container">
                <Counters
                    onReset={handleReset}
                    onDelete={handleDelete}
                    onIncrement={handleIncrement}
                    onDecrement={handleDecrement}
                    counters={count.data}
                />
            </main>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: `Tried console logging the array count and I am getting all the listed items back.` where you tried that? inside `handleDelete`?

Comment: Clicking on a button causes this error. Tried cloning the Array with the spread operator inside the event handler to keep the original state. After clicking I get Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in `handleDecrement` and `handleIncrement`

```
const counters = [...count.data];
...
setCounters(counters);
```

In you initial state, `count` is an object with `data` property.
When you `setCounters(counters)`, you set `count` as an array and after that, you try to access `.data` from `count` in the render method, but that is `undefined`, wich causes the error.

You need to change

```
setCounters(counters); // set count as an array
```

To

```
setCounters({data: counters}); // set count as an object with property 'data' as an array
```

Comment: Like a Russian boss! thank you, my friend. This way I will keep learning.

Comment: not bad for someone who just started 2 months ago with React. Thanks man!

Comment: @Galanthus you are talking about me or about you? hahaha

Comment: Nooo me :) You are JS king.

Comment: @Galanthus hahah, I wish I was

Comment: thx! helped me when trying to index into an array in state, but i wasn't setting the initial state so was getting undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are setting the count data back incorrectly.

Instead do the following.

```
setCounters({ data: counters });
```

Answer (score 0):

In some of your methods, you are setting the `counters` state as an array. But in the initialization what you are storing in the `counters` is an object with a *data* attribute (which is an array).

When you call the `handleDelete` method you are storing in the `counters` an array. So, when the component is re-rendered it tries to call the `filter` method in `counters.data` but `counter.data` does not exist at that time.

To solve the problem you can initialize the `counters` state so that it is an array:

```
const [count, setCounters] = useState([
    { id: 1, value: 4, },
    { id: 2, value: 0, },
    { id: 3,value: 0, },
    { id: 4, value: 0, },
]);
```

And take into account in the rest of your code that `count` does not have a `data` attribute anymore.

Another solution would be to update the `count` state maintaining the original structure. The `handleDelete` method would look like:

```
const handleDelete = counterId => {
    const counters = count.data.filter(c => c.id !== counterId);

    setCounters({ data: counters });
};
```